# Multiple parameter values in one string in access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an array which can have a different amount of values, depending on the situation. I want to put these values as a parameter in a query in ms access.

The problem is, if I use the following code to generate a parameter, it sends the whole string as one value to the query, which obviously does not return any rows.

```
Do Until i = size + 1
    If Not IsEmpty(gvaruocat(i)) Then
        If Not IsEmpty(DLookup("uo_cat_id", "tbl_uo_cat", "[uo_cat_id] = " & CInt(gvaruocat(i)))) Then
            If IsEmpty(get_uocat_param) Then
                get_uocat_param = CInt(gvaruocat(i))
            Else
                get_uocat_param = get_uocat_param & " OR tbl_uo_step.uo_step_cat = " & CInt(gvaruocat(i))
            End If
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

At the moment I have 'Fixed' it by generating an SQL string and leaving the query out all together.

```
get_uocat = "SELECT tbl_product.prod_descr, tbl_uo_cat.uo_cat_descr, tbl_uo_step.uo_step_descr" & vbCrLf _
          & "FROM (tbl_product INNER JOIN tbl_uo_cat ON tbl_product.prod_id = tbl_uo_cat.uo_cat_prod) INNER JOIN tbl_uo_step ON tbl_uo_cat.uo_cat_id = tbl_uo_step.uo_step_cat" & vbCrLf _
          & "WHERE (((tbl_uo_step.uo_step_cat) = " & get_uocat_param & ")) " & vbCrLf _
          & "ORDER BY tbl_product.prod_descr, tbl_uo_cat.uo_cat_descr, tbl_uo_step.uo_step_descr;"
```

This is however not very friendly to many changes. So my question is, how do I get the array to send each value as a separate parameter to the query?

**Note:** `IsEmpty()` is a custom function which checks for empty variables in case you were wondering.

Comment: Much better to use a parameter query.

Comment: Sadly, no. Not concerning the background of these values.

Comment: Allright, when I heard parameter query I was thinking along the lines of this; http://www.gcflearnfree.org/access2010/queries-how-to-create-a-parameter-query. You're right Fionuala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use a parameterized query in this case, despite your comment to the question. You just need to build the SQL string to include as many parameters as required, something like this:

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String, i As Long

' test data
Dim idArray(1) As Long
idArray(0) = 1
idArray(1) = 3

Set cdb = CurrentDb
sql = "SELECT [LastName] FROM [People] WHERE [ID] IN ("

' add parameters to IN clause
For i = 0 To UBound(idArray)
    sql = sql & "[param" & i & "],"
Next
sql = Left(sql, Len(sql) - 1) ' trim trailing comma
sql = sql & ")"
Debug.Print sql  ' verify SQL statement

Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("", sql)
For i = 0 To UBound(idArray)
    qdf.Parameters("param" & i).Value = idArray(i)
Next
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

' check results
Do Until rst.EOF
    Debug.Print rst!LastName
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
```

When I run this on my test database I get

```
SELECT [LastName] FROM [People] WHERE [ID] IN ([param0],[param1])
Thompson
Simpson
```

Comment: Allright, this is indeed a big improvement concerning readable code. But this would still force me to create and edit my SQL in VBA right? Reading back, I don't think my question was clear enough, I would really like to be able to edit my SQL in the query builder, since the ones who are going to maintain this are not knowledgedable enough in VBA.

Comment: If you want a solution that does not involve dynamic SQL then you could create a table with a single column for the specific values and then do an inner join between the two tables. However, you'd still need some VBA to put the values from the array into the single-column table, so you're not that much farther ahead.

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of the IN Clause, instead. Which would work out better.

```
Do Until i = size + 1
    If Not IsEmpty(gvaruocat(i)) Then
        If Not IsEmpty(DLookup("uo_cat_id", "tbl_uo_cat", "[uo_cat_id] = " & CInt(gvaruocat(i)))) Then
            If IsEmpty(get_uocat_param) Then
                get_uocat_param = CInt(gvaruocat(i))
            Else
                get_uocat_param = get_uocat_param & ", " & CInt(gvaruocat(i))
            End If
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Then your Query build could use,

```
get_uocat = "SELECT tbl_product.prod_descr, tbl_uo_cat.uo_cat_descr, tbl_uo_step.uo_step_descr" & vbCrLf _
              & "FROM (tbl_product INNER JOIN tbl_uo_cat ON tbl_product.prod_id = tbl_uo_cat.uo_cat_prod) INNER JOIN tbl_uo_step ON tbl_uo_cat.uo_cat_id = tbl_uo_step.uo_step_cat" & vbCrLf _
              & "WHERE ((tbl_uo_step.uo_step_cat IN (" & get_uocat_param & "))) " & vbCrLf _
              & "ORDER BY tbl_product.prod_descr, tbl_uo_cat.uo_cat_descr, tbl_uo_step.uo_step_descr;"
```